# How to add extra information in items ordered tab? Magento ver 2.x

Tags: magento2, php, grid, sales-order

I am new to M2, I need help to add extra information in the `order`.
I already have the information in the `sales_order_item` table.

Any ideas? Thank you very much

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhCSa.png
[image: Like this]

Comment: extra information like, the product more information ?

Comment: hehe sorry, I think I put it wrong
Additional information about the purchase ..
For example:
Color: Black,
Medium size

Comment: I think, if product is configurable or product having custom option,by default it will show those details there.

Comment: He does not do it, that's why I want to do it manually
:/

Comment: okies, I found out that this UI is created from here : `/rootProject/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/items.phtml

Comment: you can override the core file

Comment: Perfect, I have it, I will analyze the file

Comment: great..Happy coding ;)